# Sync data to server in chunks leads to StackoverflowException

Tags: java, android, interface, callback, stack-overflow

I am syncing huge data in chunk using onSuccessCallBack() interface method.Sending data to server in following approach shown in image. 
Here I am facing issue of StackOverflowException. How can I avoid it.

1. Should I implement BroadcastListener and will broadcast from NotifySyncCompleted() method after every cycle completion.Here in OnReceive() method of BroadcastListener I can call NextChunkSync() method.
2. Is there any way to freeing stack memory after every cycle before proceeding.
3. Even after using AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter How this problem will resolve.

[image]

```
public class SuncManager implements SuccessSyncCallBack{

public SyncNextChunk(){

    new WebServiceManager(this).syncToServer();
}


@Override
public void onSuccessForSyncCallBack() {
    SyncNextChunk();
}}
```

WebServiceManager class syncs data to server receives response and saves in database and notifies in onSuccessForSyncCallBack().

Everything works fine if iterations are less.Problem occurs only while syncing huge data in chunk.

Comment: why are you calling `new WebServiceManager(this).syncToServer();` each time, you can create a class scoped instance of `WebServiceManager` and use that to call `syncToServer()` method .. just a partial solution i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: This flow will help you]

Just make sure that you stop the service when you are done with all sync.

You can get information about intent service from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).And broadcast Receiver from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).Best luck!!!

Comment: That mean,I have to create one intent service and that I will invoke from broadcasts receivers OnReceive() method. Here I have to broadcast from NotifySyncCompleted() method. Sounds logical I will definitely try.